# No tools folder in android sdk

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

no tools folder in my android -> sdk

as I know it should be there but it isn't.
Only things id sdk folder:

--- add-ons (folder)
--- build-tools (folder)
--- docs (folder)
--- AVD Manager (app)
--- SDK manager (app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

Control panel (View by icons instead of Category (in the top right)) -> folder options -> view -> hidden files and folders:

check "Show hidden files, folders, and drivers "

Apply -> ok.